# AWS SSM Parameter Store with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-kms, aws-cloudformation

From the CFN docs I can see that I can create an [AWS::SSM::Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html).  I also see how I can create a [KMS Master Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html).

However the `type` parameter on the `SSM:Parameter` in the doc page does not list the `secure string` type.

Is there a way that I can do the following in a cloudformation template:

```
1) create KMS Key
2) use KMS key to encrypt a param
3) pull that param in User-Data for an EC2 instance
```

I will be running the CFN template from a Jenkins job with the value of the param in a jenkins password parameter.  I can also set `"NoEcho": true` on the template's parameter so it's not echoed in the CloudFormation console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a way to use a [custom resource](https://github.com/glassechidna/ssmcfn) to do this.  In combination with a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Support for this has been added so you no longer need to use a custom resource. You have to use a dynamic reference to a secure parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Using this feature you can use add `{{resolve:ssm-secure:parameter-name:version}}` to your user data within a `Fn::Join` CF intrinsic.

As of April 2019 secure strings are not available as a parameter type in cloudformation templates however the documentation states that `CloudFormation will support the Parameter Store ‘SecureString’ type in a later release.`

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/